# Php array to normal variable

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

Can `$var[$x]['seeds']` be converted into `$var`? In mysql statement like the one below, how can I use it?

```
$length=9;
$x=0;
while ($x<$length){
$query="Select fruits in ('$var[$x]['seeds']') from edible";//This query will go 9 times different seeds. 
$x++;
}
```

Please help me.

Comment: What's `$var`? Where does it come from?

Comment: is 'seeds' is fixed for $var? and it's fixed upto 9?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I hope that I understand your question correctly:

```
$query = "SELECT seeds FROM edible WHERE seeds IN ('" . $var[$x]['Apple'] . "')";
```

If you now perform: `echo $query;` you will see how the query looks like. But your question is not really clear in what your exactly want.

Also if you want to use variables in query, then look at parameterized queries. This prevents SQL injections.

Comment: You have solved my problem. I can see your code working even without testing. Thanks, you are very helpful.

Answer (score 1):

You can store that value to variable and use in query or you can use escape string .

```
$query = "Select fruits in ('".$var[$x]['seeds']."') from edible"
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you want to create a query that compares a value against a list of possible other values with SQL. I would do this with a single prepared statement:

```
$sql = 'SELECT fruits IN (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?) FROM edible';
$stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute(array_map(function($value) {
    return $value['seeds'];
}, $var));
```